Prove that the expected number of customers in an M/M/s queue is convex
I have an M/M/s queue with arrival rate $\lambda$ and service rate $\mu$, then the expected number of customers in the system with s servers is equal to $E[N_s] = \frac{\rho_s}{1-\rho_s}C(s,\rho) + \rho$ (where $\rho_s=\frac{\lambda}{s\mu}$ and $\rho=\frac{\lambda}{\mu}$), where $C(s,\rho)$ is the Erlang C formula. I want to prove that $\Delta^2 E[N_s] \geq 0$, where $\Delta^2 E[N_s] = \Delta E[N_{s+1}] - \Delta E[N_s]$ and $\Delta E[N_s]=E[N_{s+1}]-E[N_{s}]$. Now we know that we need to prove that $\frac{\rho_s}{1-\rho_s}C(s,\rho) + \frac{\rho_{s+2}}{1-\rho_{s+2}}C(s+2,\rho) \geq 2\frac{\rho_{s+1}}{1-\rho_{s+1}}C(s+1,\rho)$, but after trying to work this out for quite some time, I got stuck. Can anyone help me further?
[Edit] So I found that Harie (2011) ("Convexity Results for the Erlang Delay and
Loss Formulae When the Server Utilization Is
Held Constant"), shows that $C(s,\rho)$ is strictly convex. They state that $E[N_{s,q}]$ is strictly convex because $E[N_{s,q}]=\frac{\rho_s}{1-\rho_s}C(s,\rho)$ (Here $E[N_{s,q}]$ is the expected number of customers in the queue). Can anyone help me show that this is indeed true?

I feel like there should be a purely intuitive argument here that does not require knowledge of the formula; $\Delta E[N_s]$ should be negative and increasing because adding an extra server only helps you when there are more than $s$ customers in the system, which gets less common as $s$ increases. This might be hard to make rigorous, though.
